# Image Download button PHP

Tags: php, image

Hi i have a **bitmap** image data stored in a `variable`  , i need to provide a **button** to download this image to users file system .. , as there is no direct link for the image how to do it ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Link to a PHP script that does this:

```
header("Content-type: image/bmp");
header("Content-disposition: attachment; filename='image.bmp'");
echo $variable_containing_bitmap;
```