# Loading a image format from MySQL Blob - PHP?

Tags: php, mysql, image

My question is simply asking how take a MySQL blob that is a image format (i.e. png, gif, jpg) and save it as a temporary file for the client to load.

Thanks!

Comment: You don't need to save a temporary file. You can supply a download stream directly, just be sending the correct headers via `header()` and then echo the binary blob.

Comment: See an example here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6882367/image-download-button-php assuming your blob has been fetched into a variable.

Answer (score 0):

[`file_put_contents`](http://php.net/file-put-contents)?

Alternatively, to avoid the need for a temporary file, you could use the `data:` scheme, however you would need to know the exact type of the image in question and there are limitations in the browsers.

Comment: Thank you very much for sparing your time!